# livepatch not delivering updates for 5.15 hwe

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Another thread on the livepatch topic.

On multiple ubuntu 20.04.6 servers, running 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1-generic, we never get any livepatch updates to the kernel.
I don't see anything wrong in the configuration, and the systems are covered by an ubuntu landscape subscription.
I see that livepatch would be covered under an ubuntu pro subscription, maybe that changed as in the past we were getting livepatch coverage.

```
$ canonical-livepatch refresh
checking for patches
nothing to apply
kernel: 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1-generic
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1-generic
```

and also:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status
last check: 9 minutes ago
kernel: 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 5.15 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 5.15.0-84.93~20.04.1-generic
tier: stable
machine id: 123xyz
```